# Matching a number from a table in regex

Tags: regex, vim, windows-xp

Don't mind the weird encoding.

Is there a way (in a table like this, which starts with OF DAMAGE STABILITY) and ends with the "Flooding percentage" line, to match only numbers from the last column which are less than some value (say, 0.018)?

I'm practicing regular expressions, but this is way too much for me at this stage. So I was hoping somebody could at least recommend what would be the best way to go about it.

```
                    SUMMARY OF RESULTS OF DAMAGE STABILITY                      
 ÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ
       DAMAGE CASE               %  R  HEEL   GM     FBmin   GZ>0  GZmax  Area  
                                      (deg)   (m)     (m)   (deg)   (m)  (m.rad)
 ÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ
 109.10s                        100 1  -4.1   0.438   1.243  59.2  0.133  0.021 
                                 20 1  -6.6   0.740   2.215  63.4  0.479  0.049 
                                 40 1  -5.8   0.721   2.372  64.2  0.393  0.045 
                                 60 1  -3.2   0.728   2.537  66.8  0.277  0.041 
                                 80 1  -0.8   0.721   2.354  66.8  0.192  0.037 

 109.10p                        100 1  -4.1   0.438   1.243  59.2  0.133  0.021 
                                 20 1   4.5   0.688   2.494  65.5  0.507  0.049 
                                 40 1   3.7   0.684   2.580  66.3  0.417  0.046 
                                 60 1   1.1   0.720   2.599  68.9  0.300  0.043 
                                 80 1  -1.2   0.693   2.350  65.2  0.177  0.035 


 110.10s                        100 1  -3.0   0.748   1.837  39.7  0.494  0.049 
                                 20 1  -2.9   0.777   2.333  43.1  0.594  0.052 
                                 40 1  -2.9   0.777   2.333  42.5  0.576  0.052 
                                 60 1  -2.9   0.756   2.294  41.6  0.551  0.050 
                                 80 1  -2.9   0.748   2.077  40.7  0.520  0.049 

 110.10p                        100 1  -0.5   0.733   2.143  41.6  0.484  0.047 
                                 20 1  -0.5   0.763   2.627  45.3  0.613  0.051 
                                 40 1  -0.5   0.763   2.627  44.7  0.592  0.051 
                                 60 1  -0.5   0.740   2.593  43.8  0.558  0.049 
                                 80 1  -0.5   0.767   2.372  42.7  0.516  0.048 


 %     : Flooding percentage.                                                   
 R     : R=1 if run-off weights considered, R=0 if no run-off.                  
 HEEL  : Heel at equilibrium (negative if equilibrium is on port).              
 GM    : GM at equilibrium.                                                     
 FBmin : Minimum distance of margin line, weathertight or non-weathertight      
         points from waterline.                                                 
 GZ>0  : Range of positive GZ limited to immersion of non-weathertight openings.
 GZmax : Maximum GZ value.
```

Comment: I notice you're doing this in Vim. Would you be better off simply doing a Paste-Special into Excel or similar ?

Comment: what do you want to do with those matches? replace with another value? are you working on linux box?

Comment: @Kent - No, just check whether there are any values that are smaller than some significant value. Matching & highlighting the interesting values would help me go through the tables (there are a lot of them in every file) since now I go through the numbers manually.

Comment: @BrianAgnew - Thought of that, but since the output is in txt files, and there are a lot of them (changing all the time), it would probably slow the whole process down. I think Vim is a better option for now. Otherwise, yes, this would be simpler in Excel.

Answer (score 4):

The `0.018` example is not good, since all numbers in your last column are greater than `0.018`.... I took some minutes to find it out. I thought my vim substitution command has problem...

Looking at the example, the given range border (starts with OF DAMAGE STABILITY and ends with the "Flooding percentage") is not necessary, but you know the requirement best. I added the range in command too.

In the command below, I changed it to `0.040` so that we could see difference. The below command will add a `*` at the end of matched number.

```
 /STABILITY/,/Flooding/s/\v([0-9.-]+)\s*$/\=str2float(submatch(1))<0.040? submatch(1).'*':submatch(1)
```

short explanation:

```
 /STABILITY/,/Flooding/                                      " fit the range, as you defined
 s/                                                          " start substitution
 \v                                                          " use very magic, so that I could save some escaping
 ([0-9.-]+)\s*$/                                             " match the last number column (float or negative)
 \=str2float(submatch(1))<0.040? submatch(1).'*':submatch(1) " vimscript expression, if the value<0.040, add a '*'
```

if you are on linux box, this job is also easy to be done by awk. if you are a Microsoft person, Excel maybe (I am not sure) the good tool.

**EDIT**

From your comments, I think you didn't get what I meant.  I

the command:

```
 /STABILITY/,/Flooding/s/\v([0-9.-]+\d)\s*$/\=str2float(submatch(1))<0.040? submatch(1).'<':submatch(1)/
```

then you do search:

```
/[0-9.-]\+\d\ze<$
```

**note** that this highlighted the numbers (I still use `0.040` to see difference), also add flag/suffix `<`. you could move to next highlighted number by pressing `n`. previous `N`. if you finish "reading" the file, quit with `:q!` or `ZQ` to skip the changes.

I hope this meets your requirement.

see this example:
[image]

Comment: Whoops, sorry. It looks like I pasted the wrong table as example. The 0.018 is a characteric value, so we always compare it to that value. Instead of adding a *, how would I go about just matching (highlighting) the interesting values?

Comment: @ldigas it might be done by a script, but not an one-liner command. because regex is not a good tool to do math calculation (number comparison). I don't know what would you modify, but you could add a marker, e.g. "###" at the end of the matched number, and do your modification. when you are done with it, remove those markers. with "###" you could also easily search numbers ending with "###", then use `n` or `N` to navigate between those matches. just my 2 cents.

Comment: On the same subject, aside from regex, what would be in your opinion, a good tool for quick matching of data similar to this, yet quick in nature? By quick I mean, something, that doesn't require me to write a 40 page program for an operation like this. Such thing exists?

Comment: I dont know what would you do after the highlighting.  I assume you want to do something on the matched lines/numbers. If I were you, I would do what I said in last comment. add a suffix (###) to the number (by :s/../../) then `/###$` I can find and highlight all the numbers, also I could `n` and `N`. finally remove ###. it seems that I repeated my last comment... :(

Comment: I really wouldn't do anything - those files are merely the result which we need to check against some requirements. The problem is they tend to grow very long, and manually checking them wears people out. So I just wanted to make Vim show them in an easier-to-spot way. Highlighted numbers in a red background/white letters are easier to spot than the ones having a # or some other marker attached to them.

Answer (score 2):

Coming up with a regular expression that asserts a certain number range on a floating point number would indeed be very complex.

If you insist on using Vim (remember, it's a *text editor*, whereas filtering on structured column-based information is more suitable for a *spreadsheet*), you could use a rather relaxed regular expression to match all number "candidates", and do the exact number range assertion in a **replace-expression**. You cannot use the normal `/` search, you have to use `:substitute` (e.g. with a no-op replacement, or processing of whatever you want to achieve) to use a `:help sub-replace-expression`:

```
:%substitute/[+-]\?\d\+\.\d\+$/\=str2float(submatch(0)) < 0.018 ? 'match' : submatch(0)/
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, we deal with text files as output and pasting them in excel would significantly slow the whole thing down. Were it not like that, I would agree - excel would be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
/0.0\(2[0-1]\|[0-1][0-9]\)$
```

`$` is the end of line anchor. The first part of the grouping matches 20 and 21, so 0.021 is the largest number that this will match. The alternation after `\|` matches everything from 00 to 19.  So this regex matches the last number on the line which is between 0.021 and 0.000.

As you can see, comparing numbers is a bit annoying with regular expressions, because you need to think about the numbers as strings, and use ASCII order.